# CSS Understanding margins with respect to borders

Tags: css, w3c

I'm trying to understand a behavior I've seen when I was messing around with some html code you can see [here](http://jsbin.com/exahuv/14/edit).

You'll notice that if you change the following:

```
<div style="border: solid 1px black;">
    <div style="margin-top:50px;">
        Post Title
    </div>
</div>
```

to this (ie. "border: solid 1px black;" to "border: solid 0px black;"):

```
<div style="border: solid 0px black;">
    <div style="margin-top:50px;">
        Post Title
    </div>
</div>
```

the margin of the inner div does not effect the outer div any longer. I've been trying to find the W3.org specification which defines this behavior, but no luck. Anyone want to help?

Comment: Sometimes I used `border: 1px solid transparent` to get around this.  It's damn annoying though.  Stop collapsing my damn padding for no good reason.

Comment: Ya, I had to do exactly that. It honestly is annoying. Tis the reason I am in persuit of the W3 specification that defines this behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called "collapsing margins".

> Certain adjoining margins combine to form a single margin. Those
>   margins are said to “collapse.” Margins are adjoining if there are no
>   nonempty content, padding or border areas or clearance to separate
>   them.

- http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins
- http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#collapsing-margins

Some easier reads:

- http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins
- http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/css/margincollapsing

Comment: I had a feeling that was it, but I tried "border-collapse: separate;" and it didn't work so I figured that collapsed borders were not the reason. Do you happen to know why?

Comment: Your example is almost exactly the same as the first two examples explained [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#collapsing-margins).

Comment: sure, i get that this is in fact the answer