# Unwanted margin when setting background on HTML element in CSS

Tags: html, css, margin

So it is fairly well known that you can add a background image to the HTML tag and the BODY tag to get a double background effect without adding extra div elements. I love that you can do this, but when I attempt it extra margin gets added to the top of the BODY element.

I did find that if you added the following code:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
}
```

it will get rid of this margin, but it also makes it so I have to reset all the other elements that I didn't want to get rid of margin on.

Does anyone know of a way to just get rid of the HTML tag margin.

This:

```
html {
    margin: 0;
}
```

doesn't work BTW. It seems to be something else causing the extra spacing.

**UPDATE:**
Here is the JS Bin example. http://jsbin.com/ebefah/2

I am running an HTML5 doctype and I have gotten rid of the margin on the body as well.

**ANSWER:**
Thank you to thirtydot. The answer was the H1, due to collapsing margins. Once I got rid of the top margin on the H1 it all worked flawlessly. Thank you again!

Comment: Can you provide a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) test case? I don't feel like guessing.

Comment: `body` has a default margin in most browsers.

Comment: have you tried `body { margin: 0; }` ?

Comment: The [Default style sheet for HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html) specifies a `margin: 8px` on the body element.

Comment: Make sure the Code before the body tag is clean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The gap is coming from the `h1` (which has some `margin-top` by default), due to the effects of collapsing margins.

[Read this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197927/css-understanding-margins-with-respect-to-borders/8198076#8198076)

You possibly just want to set `margin-top: 0` on the `h1`.

Comment: This is the Answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

There is a default margin to the body ..

Try `html,body{margin:0;padding:0}`

Answer (score 0):

Use a CSS reset to normalize default styles between browsers. Yahoo have a decent CSS reset. Most elements have `margin`/`padding` applied by default on elements such as `h1`, `body`, `html` etc.

http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssreset/